# Is it possible to extract magnesium from epsom salt?

Tags: home-experiment, extraction

Is it possible (at home) to extract magnesium from $\ce{MgSO4·7H2O}$, also known as [Epsom salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium_sulfate) (or, alternatively, from $\ce{MgSO4}$)?

Comment: Do you want to extract magnesium ions, or are you actually looking for a way to get magnesium metal?

Comment: Not really.  IIRC they use the chloride for that.

Comment: you should melt magnesium acetate in a vacuum, then its only 130 degrees or so to do it.

Answer (score 12):

Supposed you are trying to obtain **magnesium metal** from Epsom salt, $\ce{MgSO4.7 H2O}$:

#### Is is worth the effort?

Magnesium metal in the form of chips (particle size 4-30 mesh) in decent purity (99.98%) is available from suppliers such as [Sigma-Aldrich](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/254118?lang=de&region=DE) for about 150 Euro per kilogram.

#### Can I use electrolysis to generate $\ce{Mg}$ metal?

Yes, but you wouldn't want to do that at home. An older industrial process uses electrolysis of **molten** magnesium chloride, $\ce{MgCl2}$ (mp. is around 700 °C). While $\ce{Mg}$ metal is formed at the cathode, chlorine gas is released at the graphite anode. Did I mention that this isn't meant to be done at home?

#### Can I convert $\ce{MgSO4}$ to something more usable to make $\ce{Mg}$ metal?

Yes, in principle. A group of Chinese researchers examined the conversion of  $\ce{MgSO4}$ to  magnesium oxide, $\ce{MgO}$ by heating in the presence of natural gas at temperatures around 500 °C and outlined their results in
[*Geochemical Journal*, **2011**, *45*, 97-108](http://www.terrapub.co.jp/journals/GJ/pdf/4502/45020097.pdf).

The initial pressure by natural gas at room temperature was 3 MPa, but upon heating to the final temperature, the pressure in the reactor was as high as 12-20 MPa! This can't be done at home and it shouldn't be.

#### What if I would have $\ce{MgO}$? What could I do with it?

Magnesium oxide, $\ce{MgO}$, is indeed the most important starting material in the production of magnesium metal in the **Pidgeon process**. Here, magnesium oxide is **heated** in the presence of silicon in an evacuated reactor. Silicon is oxidized to silicon dioxide, magnesium oxide is reduced to magnesium metal. The latter boils off (bp. around 1100 °C) and is condensed. This isn't kitchen chemistry either.

In summary, you're better off buying some magnesium metal from a supplier of your choice!

Comment: On the sulfate decomposition, don't forget the toxic sulfur-bearing fumes.  Also the flammability of natural gas, which is needed to reduce the sulfur compounds (otherwise the acid-base interaction between $\ce{MgO}$ and $\ce{SO3}$ is so strong that you'd need a much higher temperature to decompose the sulfate).

Answer (score 1):

You need molten salts of some kind or a mercury cathode to get metal.

Source: http://www.scienceforums.net/topic/36363-extracting-magnesium/

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is possible. If you electrolyze MgSO4(aq), one of the products will be magnesium hydroxide. If you you add Hydrochloric acid to it you get magnesium chloride 2HCl(aq)+Mg(OH)₂(s)⟶MgCl₂(aq)+2H₂O(l), electrolyze that and you get magnesium and chlorine gas, the last step must be done outdoors
Here's a useful link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BThiJpbBJQ